# Getting a.ref is not a function error when upgraded to angularfire 1.2

Tags: firebase, angularfire

Following codebase used to work with firebase 2.3.1 and Angularfire 1.1.3

```
Var fb = new firebase("https://database name.firebaseio.com");

var fbObj = $firebaseObject(fb.child("users/" + userId));
```

I upgraded to firebase3.0 and Angularfire 1.2.

As a result, here is how the above code got modified:

```
var config = {/* ...  */};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var fb = firebase.database().ref();

var fbObj = $firebaseObject(fb.child("users/" + userId))
```

The above code however threw error such as a.ref is not a function when instantiating fbObj.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should not upgrade your firebase to 3.0 because AngularFire upgrade to 3.0 has not been completed.

See Issue in GitHub : https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/718

Comment: Thanks for the link. I reverted back.

Comment: if this is the correct answer, you should mark it to help others in the community @Ajitesh

Comment: AngularFire now supports the new SDK.