# new firebase: use of $firebaseArray

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

With the new Firebase, I can't find the way to use $firebaseArray.

It used to be:

> $firebaseArray(new Firebase('https://......../users'));

Now, with the new Firebase, I tried:

> $firebaseArray(firebase.database().ref('users'))

But this gives me an error, saying "Must pass a valid Firebase reference to $firebaseArray".

What is it that I don't understand?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369657/getting-a-ref-is-not-a-function-error-when-upgraded-to-angularfire-1-2

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md

4. Inject the AngularFire Services

var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('users');

$scope.users = $firebaseArray(ref);